# AWS - List to Csv in Ruby and Unix commands

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I am trying to use RUBY to read the list of S3 bucket objects. I want to use

```
`aws s3 ls 'Aws bucket details'`
```

to generate my code. its not working can someone help

```
p  bucketName = ARGV[0]
p  prefix  = ARGV[1]
p  reversedExchange = ARGV[2]
p  startDateIp  = ARGV[3]
p  endDateIp =  ARGV[4]
p  outputFile = ARGV[5]

p ENV['HTTPS_PROXY']

require 'date'
p startDate =  Date.new(startDateIp[0,4].to_i, startDateIp[4,2].to_i, startDateIp[6,2].to_i)
p endDate =  Date.new(endDateIp[0,4].to_i, endDateIp[4,2].to_i, endDateIp[6,2].to_i)


#p startDate - endDate

while startDate - endDate < 0 do
   p revStr = 'xxxxx'
   p s3URL = 's3://' + bucketName + '/' + prefix + '/' + revStr + '/'
   totalC = 0
   p ` echo aws s3 ls #{s3URL} --recursive | wc -l >> #{totalC}`
   p `echo  #{s3URL}`
   p `echo #{totalC}`
   p totalC
   p totalCount = `echo aws s3 ls #{s3URL} --recursive`
end
```

I am unable to get the list of files using aws s3 ls command [ totalCount variable is not coming as expected]. if i am doing shell scripting i am able to get it. The count is coming as zero\n always i dunno why for ruby.

Comment: Try running your command in the shell before using in your Ruby code, I don't think you want `echo` you are also using `>>` wrongly, I don't think it will achieve want you want in bash(it appends to a file) or in ruby(appends to a string/list or ...)

Comment: hi the command in the totalcount line works perfectly in bash shell. i am getting recursive list of files. Echo also works for the line i used totalC. in shell in totalC it gives everything. not in ruby

Comment: I agree with @bjhaid's points (except that in Ruby it's << and not >> that adds to a collection).  There look to be many errors in your command. In addition to the points he mentioned, you're piping the list to wc, thereby losing the list and getting the word count statistics as the final result. How about trying this: p `aws s3 ls #{s3URL} --recursive`

Comment: Hi Keith, Tried it too, I am unable to still point out the error. It's still not getting the list of files.

Comment: @KeithBennett you are correct